# Auto sign-in to an embedded Kibana dashboard iframe

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

### What I Want to Achieve

I pasted a Kibana dashboard's iframe code in my webapp, which works fine. I'm trying to skip the sign-in screen.

### What I Have Tried

Since I already have the user's credentials in memory, I figured an AJAX call to `/api/v1/auth/login` before loading the embedded visualization should set the appropriate cookie and skip the sign-in screen.

The issue is, Kibana will only accept the request if it has a `kbn-version` header. But if I add a `kbn-version` header to the AJAX request, the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request fails with:

> "CORS error: Some headers are not allowed"

I have tried adding `kbn-version` to some Hapi configuration settings such as `server.cors.additionalHeaders`, `server.cors.headers`, `server.cors.exposedHeaders`, and `server.cors.additionalExposedHeaders` but none of them seem to work.

This is my `custom-kibana.yml` file:

```
$ cat custom-kibana.yml 
---
# Default Kibana configuration from kibana-docker.

server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
server.cors : true
server.cors.origin: ['*']
server.cors.additionalHeaders: ['kbn-xsrf', 'kbn-version']
server.cors.headers: ["accept", "authorization", "content-type", "if-none-match", "origin", "kbn-xsrf", "kbn-version"]
server.cors.exposedHeaders: ["accept", "authorization", "content-type", "if-none-match", "origin", "kbn-xsrf", "kbn-version"]
server.cors.additionalExposedHeaders: ['kbn-xsrf', 'kbn-version']
# server.ssl.enabled: true
# server.ssl.key: kibana.pem
# server.ssl.certificate: kibana-key.pem
elasticsearch.url: https://localhost:9200
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.username: kibanaserver
elasticsearch.password: <pw>
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]

opendistro_security.multitenancy.enabled: true
opendistro_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: ["Private", "Global"]
opendistro_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
```

### My Question

How do I skip the sign-in screen, either by solving the issue I encountered or in any other way.

Comment: have the same problem

Comment: Did you get the solution? Where you able to figure out?

Comment: Have you resolved this?